# How to remove the text "React App" and date from the top while print page reactjs web page?

Tags: reactjs, printing

[image]

How to remove the the text "React App" from the top of print page and the date from the top left corner ?

Comment: Untick "Headers and footers"?

Answer (score 0):

The date is put in by the browser. Doubt you can change that. User has to turn off the header and footer themselves.

You can change the app title with React Helmet

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot remove that as this is the information set from the browser, so the user should set that from his browser settings, in chrome for example there is the more settings tab where the user can uncheck the header and the footer of the page on print 
[image: chrome print settings]